# How do I load multiple CSV into DataFrames in Julia?

Tags: julia

I already know how to load a single CSV into a DataFrame:

```
using CSV
using DataFrames    
df = DataFrame(CSV.File("C:\\Users\\username\\Table_01.csv"))
```

How would I do this when I have several CSV files, e.g. `Table_01.csv`, `Table_02.csv`, `Table_03.csv`?
Would I create a bunch of empty DataFrames and use a for loop to fill them? Or is there an easier way in Julia? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/function/map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want multiple data frames (not a single data frame holding the data from multiple files) there are several options.

Let me start with the simplest approach using broadcasting:

```
dfs = DataFrame.(CSV.File.(["Table_01.csv", "Table_02.csv", "Table_03.csv"]))
```

or

```
dfs = @. DataFrame(CSV.File(["Table_01.csv", "Table_02.csv", "Table_03.csv"]))
```

or (with a bit of more advanced stuff, using function composition):

```
(DataFrame∘CSV.File).(["Table_01.csv", "Table_02.csv", "Table_03.csv"])
```

or using chaining:

```
CSV.File.(["Table_01.csv", "Table_02.csv", "Table_03.csv"]) .|> DataFrame
```

Now other options are `map` as it was suggested in the comment:

```
map(DataFrame∘CSV.File, ["Table_01.csv", "Table_02.csv", "Table_03.csv"])
```

or just use a comprehension:

```
[DataFrame(CSV.File(f)) for f in ["Table_01.csv", "Table_02.csv", "Table_03.csv"]]
```

(I am listing the options to show different syntactic possibilities in Julia)

Comment: Thanks! I prefer e.g. broadcasting, because I can still use keywords there, but good to learn about other possibilities.

Comment: And I guess for renaming the columns of the dfs, I'd use sth like 
`for i in 1:length(dfs)
    rename!(dfs[i],[Symbol("A"),Symbol("B"),Symbol("C")])
end`

Comment: you do not need to use `Symbol`. Just write `foreach(df -> rename!(df, ["A", "B", "C"]), dfs)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have done it, but there might be an easier way.

```
using DataFrames, Glob
import CSV

function readcsvs(path)
    files=glob("*.csv", path) #Vector of filenames. Glob allows you to use the asterisk.
    numfiles=length(files)    #Number of files to read.
    tempdfs=Vector{DataFrame}(undef, numfiles) #Create a vector of empty dataframes.
    for i in 1:numfiles
        tempdfs[i]=CSV.read(files[i]) #Read each CSV into its own dataframe.
    end
    masterdf=outerjoin(tempdfs..., on="Column In Common") #Join the temporary dataframes into one dataframe.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution where you don't have to explicitly enter filenames:

```
using CSV, Glob, DataFrames
path = raw"C:\..." # directory of your files (raw is useful in Windows to add a \)
files=glob("*.csv", path) # to load all CSVs from a folder (* means arbitrary pattern)
dfs = DataFrame.( CSV.File.( files ) ) # creates a list of dataframes

# add an index column to be able to later discern the different sources
for i in 1:length(dfs)
    dfs[i][!, :sample] .= i # I called the new col sample
end

# finally, if you want, reduce your collection of dfs via vertical concatenation
df = reduce(vcat, dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of open write and close process. Reading is similar too.

```
    function main()
    f_max=365
    data=zeros(Float64,100,f_max)
    data[:,:].=rand()

    filenames=[]
    for i=1:f_max
        ci=string(i)
         filename="./testdata"*ci*".dat"
         push!(filenames,filename)
     end
     

    files = [open(file,"w") for file in filenames]


    for i=1:f_max
        write(files[i],data[:,i])
    end

    #println(odata[1,1]," ",odata[1,2])

    for i=1:f_max
        close(files[i])
    end

    end

    main()
```